# Getting vailidation anomalies in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

I'm following this (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/getting-started-with-mvc/getting-started-with-mvc-part7), but I am seeing some strange things I when I view the webpage.

1) The `ReleaseDate` says its a required filed (even though its not marked as such in the code) , and I cannot see why its doing this.

and

2) the `Price` "works" if the values is `100.50`, or less . if its `100.51` or higher, then the message kicks in. My understanding is that the message should kick in @ `100.01`... or am I wrong ?

```
namespace Movies.Models
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

public partial class Movie
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Titles are required")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public System.DateTime ReleaseDate { get; set; }

    public string Genre { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "The Price is required.")]
    [Range(5, 100, ErrorMessage = "Movies cost between £5 and £100.")]
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
}
```

[image]

Could someone point out what I'm doing wrong ?

thanks

**view code is**

```
@model Movies.Models.Movie

@{
ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Movie</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Genre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Genre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Genre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Price, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Price, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Price, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: where is your view code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First question.

Make your `DateTime` nullable like this:

```
public System.DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
```

Second question:

Specify Range number type to `double` with literal `d` like this:

```
[Range(5d, 100d, ErrorMessage = "Movies cost between £5 and £100.")]
public decimal Price { get; set; }
```

Comment: I amended to fix it with [Range(5.00, 100.00, ErrorMessage = "Movies cost between £5 and £100.")]

Comment: just need to figure out what the ReleaseDate is saying its required, even though I haven't said it is.

Comment: @GeraldOakham that's basically the same. Yout dots `.` make your numers `double`. literal `M` make numbers `decimal`. So your solution in general may work wrong still.

Comment: @GeraldOakham that's wierd, but i update question, maby it will help you

Comment: if I add M, it get the message "cannot convert decimal to int"

Comment: @GeraldOakham ok, you right, just figureout that this attribute doesn't have overload for decimal, only double